# How scalable is timer service in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

What limits the number of timers & their max duration as defined in [ProcessFunctions](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/datastream/operators/process_function/#timers) in Apache Flink?

How does Flink deal with having large number ( ~100 million ) of long ( 24 hours ) timers?

Since all the 100 million keys and corresponding fault tolerant state (ValueState) would be alive, does that mean we would need large amounts of [managed memory](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup_tm/#configure-heap-and-managed-memory)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink timers aren't large objects, so having ~100 million of them is perfectly feasible. Normally timers are kept in the state backend, along with other keyed state -- so they can either be on-heap, or in RocksDB. There is an option to keep timers on-heap even if your other keyed state is in RocksDB, but that's generally not advisable.

Regardless of whether your timers are kept on-heap or in RocksDB, Flink will checkpoint and restore them, like other managed state.

Assuming you are using RocksDB, then you will want to have enough managed memory to allow RocksDB to be well behaved. Exactly what this entails typically requires some use-case-specific experimentation.

---

Update: During checkpointing, on-heap timers are persisted during the synchronous phase -- i.e., while the operator is stalled. This is the primary reason why I recommend keeping your timers in RocksDB, unless you don't have very many timers (per task), or can tolerate these hiccups in processing.

Comment: Makes sense. Following the fraud detection example but with long timers like 24 hours, how would checkpointing look like? For some messages the timer state would be cleared before 24 hours but for other timer will need to be run for it's entire duration before going to the next operator i.e Sink. Since checkpointing happens before going to the next operator, wouldn't it mean that the checkpointing would be delayed by 24 hours for many messages?

Comment: (1) timers are deduplicated at the level of (key, timestamp) -- so for any given key and timestamp, there can be at most one timer. (2) they are immutable (except that they can deleted). (3) checkpoints don't sit around waiting for timers to fire; the checkpoint will simply record the (key, timestamp) pairs that are still pending.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. My question is more in context with snapshot barriers. An operator state is check-pointed just before emitting the barriers to their output streams. If for 99% of keys the timers in a `KeyedProcessFunction` (operator) are cleared well before `onTimer` is called, then does it mean that the snapshot N would be bottlenecked by the 1% keys for which the timer must run it's course?

Comment: I've expanded my answer -- see above.